# PaperJS with html elements

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to add a input box in specific points( `onclick` ). How can i do this. For better understanding please refer [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DBfRT/)

And this is my code:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
    var m=0;

    function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var path = new PointText({
                        point: event.point,
                        content: 'The contents of the point text',
                        fillColor: 'black',
                        fontSize: 25
                    });
    path.removeOnDrag();
    }

     function onMouseUp(event) {
        m++;
        var point = event.point;
        createInput(point);
    }

    function createInput(point){
            console.log(point); 
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="x-text">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="y-text">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="content-text">

$("#canvas").click(function(e){
                        if(set==5){
                        var offset = $(this).offset();
                        $("#position").text((e.clientX - offset.left) + ", " + (e.clientY - offset.top));
                        $("#position").empty();
                        var input = $("<input type='text' value='' class='addtext' id='addText'>");
                        var save = $("<input type='button' class='save' value='save' id='save'>");
                        var discard = $("<input type='button' class='discard' value='discard' id='disc'>");
                        $("#position").append(input);
                        $("#position").append(save);
                        $("#position").append(discard);
                        $("#position").css('position', 'absolute');
                        $("#position").css('left', e.clientX - offset.left);
                        $("#position").css('top', e.clientY);
                        var xcor = $("#x-text");
                        var ycor = $("#y-text");
                        var ctext = $("#content-text");
                        var atext = $("#addText");
                        discard.click(function(){
                        $(this).parent().empty();
                        });
                        save.click(function(){
                            ctext.val(atext.val());
                            xcor.val(e.clientX - offset.left);
                            ycor.val(e.clientY);
                            $(this).parent().empty();

                        });
                    }
                });
```

Here is the paperJS `onMouseMove()` funciton

```
function onMouseMove(event){
                if(set == 5){
                document.getElementById('save').onclick = function (){
                    m++;
                    var xcor = document.getElementById('x-text').value;
                    var ycor = document.getElementById('y-text').value;
                    var cont = document.getElementById('content-text').value;
                    var text = new PointText({
                        point: [xcor, ycor - 150],
                        content: cont,
                        fillColor: 'black',
                        fontSize: 25
                        });
                    var txt = new Group();
                    txt.addChild(text);
                    createElem('Notes', m, txt);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working soluton: http://jsfiddle.net/DBfRT/2/

The idea is to update the PointText.content on every frame with user keyBoard input value.

```
var m=0;
var input = '';
var inputPrepend = 'User input: ';
var inputs = [];

function onKeyUp(event) {
    // add user key inputs into the input variable
    input += event.key;
}

 function onMouseUp(event) {
    m++;
    var point = event.point;
    var path = new PointText({
                    point: point,
                    content: inputPrepend + input,
                    fillColor: 'black',
                    fontSize: 25
                });
    inputs.push(path);
}


function onFrame(e) {
    for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length;i++) {
        // loop through every input and update it's content 
        inputs[i].content = inputPrepend + input;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is reading every key(`BACKSPACE, SHIFT, ETC.,`). What i need is on clicking open text box with save and delete option. so that it makes easy for editing.

Comment: I am not here to write full functional code for you for some webpage you are creating. I'm here to answer a question you asked and nothing more. You DID NOT ask for an openable textbox with save and delete option. Just asked how to create an input box and that does my answer answer

Comment: Ok thank you for you answer. See my question mentioned as **trying to add input box**

Comment: PointText.content DOES NOT support HTML. So you can't just add html input element onto the canvas. Use jQuery to do that if you really need to.

Comment: Is there any possibility to draw a line with arrow using paperJS.

Comment: Please see your other question with my answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991895/paperjs-to-draw-line-with-arrow
Also to make sure: "input box" does not always mean an HTML element. Input box is just a place where user can enter something and on canvas this is usually done using no HTML at all.

Answer (score 0):

[PointText.content](http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem#content) DOES NOT support HTML. So you can't just add html input element onto the canvas using paperJS.